# Vertical alignment of form controls in a table row

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align a table row of form controls, as in this jsbin example:

http://jsbin.com/umeyud/6

I only care about IE8+, recent Firefox and recent Chrome (sorry Safari & Opera!)

While I can get pretty close, I wish I could get the "Label" on the left to align nicely with the first line of all the text displayed on all the other controls.

An added bonus would be to get the checkboxes to be vertically centered to the middle the first line of text.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Enjoy!

I needed 4px for IE & Opera, 6px for the others

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!--
  Created using jsbin.com
  Source can be edited via http://jsbin.com/umeyud/6/edit
-->
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<style id="jsbin-css">
div
{
    display: inline-block;
}

body,td,input,select,textarea 
{ 
    font: 14pt Arial 
}

.multi td 
{ 
    white-space: nowrap; 
}

.q, .vAlign
{ 
    padding-top: 0px;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-top: 4px;
}

table
{
 display: inline-table;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="q"><div>Label</div></td>
      <td class="a text" style='vertical-align: top'><input type="text" value="Hello, World!"/></td>
      <td class="a text" style='vertical-align: top'><textarea>Hello, World!</textarea></td>

      <td class="a yesno vAlign" style='vertical-align: top'><div><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;</div></td>
      <td class="a single" style='vertical-align: top'><select><option>Option 1</option></select</td>
      <td class="a multi vAlign" style='vertical-align: top'>
        <input type='checkbox'/>Option 1<br>
        <input type='checkbox'/>Option 2<br>
        <input type='checkbox'/>Option 3
      </td>
      <td class="a picture"><img src="#" width=160 height=120></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't really achieve what I was looking for - having to manually tweak browser-specific offsets won't work for my use case.